# Javascript get real path in any situation ($.ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

My project has the following structure:

```
Sil
    -> css
    -> js
    -> clients
         -> index.php
         -> response.php
    index.php
```

My problem is on the folder clients.

My url can have multiple choices, some of them are:

```
http://localhost/Sil/clients/
http://localhost/Sil/clients/all/
http://localhost/Sil/clients/stackoverflow/2
http://localhost/Sil/clients/stackoverflow/2/technology/5
```

As you can see I use `.htaccess` to write rules.

That said, the problem here is with the url inside the `$.ajax.`. I use the following code inside the `clients/index.php` file.

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'response.php?type=add',
});
```

This code works perfectly **if and only if** my url is `http://localhost/Sil/clients/`.

In case the url are the other options said above, it won't work, because the file URL output will be:

```
http://localhost/Sil/clients/all/response.php?type=add
```

Which is clearly wrong.

**I have already solved this issue by using a complete url**, but I do not believe this is the best approach since when I have to upload the files to the server by FTP I have to change in every `$.ajax` from `localhost` to my domain name.

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'http://localhost/Sil/response.php?type=add',
});
```

What other options do I have? I've tried, without success, the `window.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either start the URL with a slash in order to specify the "root directory":

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/Sil/clients/response.php?type=add',
});
```

or use a `<base>` tag in HTML:

```
<base href="http://localhost/Sil/clients/" /> 
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url : 'response.php?type=add',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, it solved. I have tried before only "/clients/response.php"..I was near by! :D

Btw, edit your answer to `/Sil/clients/response.php?type=add` (which is the correct), and I will accept in minutes.

Comment: Hey, one more thing. This will work on a real domain? Because on a real domain I don't actually have a folder called "Sil". The ftp has, as you know, `public_html/` and not `public_html/Sil/`

Comment: @user3355243 Then all you need to change (if you don't use `/` in the start of your URL's) is your `<base>` path and everything is fixed.

Comment: but, that means that whenever I upload my files to FTP I need to change in every page to `href="http:://mydomain.com/"`, because they wont work if I let it be `href="http://localhost/Sil/clients"` - I suppose?

Comment: @user3355243 Unless you use PHP or another server-side language then yes - you need to change it on every site or copy the folder structure from localhost. What I tend to do to avoid this is use subdomains instead (and your `hosts` file) so you'd be accessing `funclient.localhost/`, but you'd still have to change the `href`.